# Strategy to avoid ClassCastException in Java

Tags: java, c#

In C#, to avoid class casting exceptions, I would do something like this:

> Thing thing = createThing();
>
> Animal animal = thing as Animal;
>
> if (animal != null) {
>
> ```
>  //do something
> ```
>
> }

I would like to do a runtime check in Java, and I would strongly prefer not to throw ClassCastException if I don't have to.  What is appropriate strategy for this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`instanceof` is the Java equivalent of C#'s `is`.  There's no direct equivalent of `as`; you have to do the downcast after checking.

```
if (thing instanceof Animal) {
    Animal animal = (Animal)thing;
    ...
}
```

Or, if you really want to have a variable that is `null` if the cast would fail, try

```
Animal animal = (thing instanceof Animal) ? (Animal)thing : null;
```

Comment: for pointing out that the as operator also does the cast operation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intanceOf` operator in Java. The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. Follow more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: + (2-1) or `isAssisnableFrom()`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `instanceof` operator in Java

`The java instanceof operator is used to test whether the object is an instance of the specified type (class or subclass or interface).`

```
      class Shape{}  
      class Round extends Shape{                    //Round inherits Shape
             public static void main(String args[]){  
                 Round round=new Round();  
                 System.out.println(round instanceof Shape);   //true  
    }  
      }
```